# Node, Express JS, 404 response on all newly added routes on deployed site only

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, digital-ocean

My app is created using node and express, and hosted on a digital ocean VPS using NGINX as a reverse proxy, running Ubuntu 20.04. when i first deployed it to the said VPS everything was working perfectly, but when i started adding new routs to my server application, they would work perfectly fine on local host when i test them but when i deploy (update the repo) on the VPS the deployed site would respond to ALL new routs with error 404, be it post or get requests..the older routs would keep working fine though..the error messages i get are standard express errors

```
Cannot GET /route
```

i checked my node server file and i see that it's up to date and it should be routing everything just fine but it doesn't..
i tried to change nginx configurations, i tried changing the node version that was on the working server out of despair but no new routs are accepted at all

my node code:

```
let express = require("express");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
let hbs = require("express-handlebars");
let app = express();
const omnirouter=require("./omnirouter")

const dbURI = "mongodb stuff";

mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);
mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.connect(dbURI).then((result) => {
  app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("connected");
  })
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});



//JSON Parser
app.use(express.json());

//static files
app.use("/assets", express.static('assets'));
app.use("/scripts", express.static('scripts'));
app.use("/styles", express.static('styles'));

//view engine 
app.engine('hbs', hbs({
  runtimeOptions: {
    allowProtoPropertiesByDefault: true,
    allowProtoMethodsByDefault: true
  },
  defaultLayout: "",
  layoutsDir: "",
}));
app.set("views", __dirname);
app.set("view engine", "hbs");

//route handling
app.use(omnirouter)
```

my nginx configuration (i changed it multiple times and this is what exists on the server now)

```
server {
   root /var/www/html;

   index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

   server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

   location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/; #whatever port your app runs>
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                }

   listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
   listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = www.domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed..the problem wasn't with nginx or node js..i was running my node app as a background process using pm2..i didn't know i had to restart the service whenever i made a change to the server software like i used to do offline.

it will be worth a try if anyone ever forgets about doing this.

```
pm2 restart app.js
```